# Generate date list without using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, datetime

I have 2 columns "startTime" and "endTime" in my dataframe which are in datetime format.

[image]

i want a column which will have dates between the range(starttime, endtime) in every row corresponding to the start and end time.
I can do this using pd.daterange if I iterate using for loop using start as starttime and end as endtime for every row.

But i want to do this as a vectorized operation or in other words in a way that is computationally much faster.

in simpler terms i want to do this without the for loop if possible.

I tried to do this using the apply function but not able to do that.

I want to get  df["temp"] without using for loop.

[image]

Comment: `apply` _is_ a `for` loop, just with different syntax. I don't think there's any vectorized way

Comment: try `df['temp'] = pd.date_range()`

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). Also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).